# How to find derivative of $[1-F(v)]^{n}$ and $1-[1-F(v)]^{n}$?

Tags: calculus

How can I find the derivative with respect to $v$ for the following two equations:
$$[1-F(v)]^{n} \tag{1}$$
and
$$1-[1-F(v)]^{n} \tag{2}$$
where
$$F'(v)=f(v)$$

Comment: Have you studied the chain rule?

Comment: Well, you have to show that by induction.

Comment: Note: An "equation" must have an "equal" sign in it (hence the name). What you give are not "equations", they are expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the chain rule:
$$\Big((1-F(v))^n\Big)'=(1-F(v))'n(1-F(v))^{n-1}=-f(v)n(1-F(v))^{n-1}$$
Similarly:
$$\Big(1-(1-F(v))^n\Big)'=0-(-f(v)n(1-F(v))^{n-1})=f(v)n(1-F(v))^{n-1}$$

Comment: got it, thank you so much!